# Auto layout issue in calculator app in iOS through GUI

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-autolayout

I'm learning auto layout in iOS and trying to create calculator app to try auto layout design. But i don't know where it is going wrong while creating constraints to all buttons and label. I have set x and y co-ordinates to 0 for corner buttons and for other ones i have done vertical spacing constraint with adjacent buttons.

But the result look like this:

[image]

Expected result:

￼[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMlsa.png)

Comment: clean the constraints up again / remove them, think precisely about how they should be set up and then add them again. we can not help you just from the screenshot except telling you that your constraints are pretty messed up

Comment: can we have your targeted design you want to get. so can help u

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to first take up 1 or 2 adjacent controls (buttons) and apply the autolayout constraints to them and check their behaviour for different device orientation and different screen sizes (using different device on simulator) and check if their behaviour is as per your expectations.

Once you get this right, you can include other buttons as well. It should be must simpler this way.

Apple documentation for constraints in IB tutorials is available at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html).